# How to export Stata regressions to multiple sheets in Excel

Tags: excel, stata

I am using Stata and have this problem:

Suppose I have two outcome variables `y1` and `y2` and three regressors `x1`, `x2`, and `x3`: you can simulate them, for this question data isn't really important.

Then, suppose I make these regressions with this `foreach` loop

```
foreach y in y1 y2 {
    
    reg `y' x1
    outreg2 using "./here goes my working directory/results_`y'.xlsx, excel replace ctitle(Model 1)

    reg `y' x1 x2
    outreg2 using "./here goes my working directory/results_`y'.xlsx, excel append ctitle(Model 2)

    reg `y' x1 x2 x3
    outreg2 using "./here goes my working directory/results_`y'.xlsx, excel append ctitle(Model 3)
}
```

So I will have two Excel documents, one for `y1` and other for `y2`. Each document will have one sheet containing a 3-column regression table.

How can I have just one document with two sheets, one containing the regression table for `y1` and the other containing the regression table for `y2`?

I didn't see a `sheet` option in the `outreg2` documentation for the Excel part.

In my case there are lots of regressions so copy and paste into a single document isn't a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to do that in `outreg2`, but even if there is, I think there is a better way to do this. I recommend that when working with outputs in Excel that also allows for manual changes you should separate raw output files from the final file.

So in your code, create one file per output.

```
foreach y in y1 y2 {
    
    reg `y' x1
    outreg2 using "./results/raw/results_a_`y'.xlsx", excel ctitle(Model 1)

    reg `y' x1 x2
    outreg2 using "./results/raw/results_b_`y'.xlsx", excel ctitle(Model 2)

    reg `y' x1 x2 x3
    outreg2 using "./results/raw/results_b_`y'.xlsx", excel ctitle(Model 3)
}
```

This will generate 6 files in the `/raw/` folder.

Then create the file `./results/results.xlsx`. This is your final file. Then create a sheet for each file. In cell A1 in the sheet where you want the results in `"./results/raw/results_a_y1.xlsx"` add this formula `=[results_a_y1.xlsx]Sheet1!A1`. Then you can extend that to as many cells as you want. You might have to do this manually for it to work (see for example [here](https://blog.coupler.io/how-to-link-excel-files)).

You will get excessive `0`s in cells that are empty in the raw file. Just delete the formula there.

The benefit of this workflow is that you can edit the final file in terms of colors, cell sizes, lines, manual titles etc. without those edits are being overwritten next time you re-run your Stata script as the data script only overwrites the raw files.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure about the command, but you can combine multiple Excel files into spreadsheets in one single file in a relatively simple way, check the second option showed in the following link:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/merge-multiple-csv-files-excel/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `asdocx` for this. See this example where I created and used some dummy data to match it with your description of the problem.

If you want to keep on adding regressions to the same table, then do not add the option `reset`. Option `reset` starts a new table. Option `nest` creates a nested regression table of the type created by `outreg2`. And option `cnames()` adds a column title to each regression.

```
asdocx reg y x1, cnames(Model1) save(Model1.xlsx) sheet(Model1) replace nest
asdocx reg y x2, cnames(Model2)  sheet(Model2)  nest reset
asdocx reg y x3, cnames(Model3)  sheet(Model3)  nest reset
```

The Excel file looks like this. You can find more on nested regression by visiting this link https://asdocx.com/examples/regressions/nested/

Note: I am the author of asdoc and asdocx.

[image]

Comment: Attaullah: Since `asdocx` is for sale, it's conventional to flag explicitly in the answer that you are the author.

Comment: Dear Nick Cox: Thanks for the hint. I have now mentioned it.

Comment: Fine. The backslashed item  in the output is presumably not intended.

Comment: You are right. '\i' is a formatting directive used to make the text italic. When exporting to MS Word, this is taken care of. In the next update, I will ensure it does not appear in Excel, LaTeX, or HTML files.

Comment: No charge for bug report!